# mongo query - Find the last 5 docs with a NOT as well

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am having a small issue at the moment with a query, in that it returns the "doc" that I expect to be excluded.

```
db.offers.find({"offerImage1": { $exists : true },"offerStatus": {$not: {$ne: "Cancelled"}}}).sort({ $natural: 1 }).limit(5)
```

I would like to get back all "docs" that include a "offerImage1" key, and the "offerStatus" NOT cancelled, but as I said, I get back the canceled docs.

I think its just a syntax issue but any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using combination of `$not` and `$ne` operator in your query for `offerStatus` field which would evaluate to - "Records with offer status not, not equal to Cancelled" and hence you are getting cancelled records.

You need to remove `$not` operator from query, for it to work fine.

```
db.offers.find({"offerImage1": { $exists : true },"offerStatus": {$ne: "Cancelled"}}).sort({ $natural: 1 }).limit(5)
```

Comment: Thank you  @User97 much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a Mongo DB instance to test, but is it not a problem with a double neg ? 
Did you try just

```
db.offers.find({"offerImage1": { $exists : true },"offerStatus": {$not: {$eq: "Cancelled"}}}).sort({ $natural: 1 }).limit(5)
```